# Mixing Java 6 and Java 8 in one setup

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I have multi-aplication system based on Java 6. Each application runs on own Tomcat server installed on **one or more** hardware servers (linux). Applications using Hibernate (3 and 4 - not unified so far), Spring 3.x. Applications implements Hessian API to communicate each other.

I'd like to migrate one application to Java 8 but only this one. This application is in early developing state so I can do it easily.

Is it possible in my case to mix both Java 6  and Java 8 applications on one target installation? If so, what is important to take care during migration and further development?

Comment: Yes. Since your apps don't seem to share anything except the hardware and the linux OS, you should have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

The Java platform strongly upholds its promise of backward compatibility. You should have no problem running an application developed for Java 6 on a Java 8 runtime.

Comment: Does Spring version matter?
I found that: https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/27/spring-framework-4-0-3-released-with-java-8-support-now-production-ready